# Qt6.4.2 webengine configuration failed

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-20.04, qt6, qtwebengine

**Ubuntu 20.04**
I need to install qt6 including qtwebengine package, but when I run configuration `./configure -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -force-debug-info` I get a message that some of the required libraries to support qpa-xcb are not found.

```
WARNING: QtWebEngine won't be built. Could not find all necessary libraries for qpa-xcb support. X11:YES LIBDRM:YES XCOMPOSITE:YES XCURSOR:YES XRANDR:YES XI:YES XPROTO:YES XSHMFENCE:YES XTST:YES
```

It is a bit confusing because all the libraries are present in both the error list and the qt requirements list.

I have already checked all the dependencies that I found in official docs and on some forums. I also got note warning from qt `Note: Disabling X11 Accessibility Bridge: D-Bus or AT-SPI is missing.`, I am not sure if this is related to my problem, but in any case d-bus and at-spi are also installed.

Comment: You may have more chances posting the entire output of configure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on **Ubuntu 22.04**, even though I was sure I had `dbus` installed. I fixed my problem by installing development package for `libatspi`.

```
sudo aptitude install libatspi2.0-dev
```